# General Questions/Points to be considered during Data Migration Process

Tags: migration, informatica

With the advent of enterprise level platform that Salesforce now provides, Data Migration and Integration now plays crucial scope role in any of Salesforce implementation.

I want to know what are the generic questions to be asked during Data Migration processes.

Example : DataStage, Informatica Cloud Services are some of top third party products that provide seamless Data Migration functionalities for Source/Legacy Systems data to be migrated to Salesforce. I want to know what are the points to be considered to approve these tools for any of Salesforce Data Migration Implementation.

Answer (score 5):

There are some very good resources out there on data migration in Salesforce.  I recommend looking at the [Data Migration Consultant Resource Center pages](http://developer.force.com/consultants/crc_page?name=DataMigration) to get you going on planning a process/strategy.  They have detailed information on Project Phases, Best Practices, Data Quality, Tools, and even some specific documentation on extracting from some common systems.  It also has example templates for planning.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this

1. Do they support relevant end points you need for migration
2. Salesforce Bulk API support - Important for large volume
3. Transformation features (e.g. filter rows, custom routines, RegEx)
4. Learning curve

I use these tools
1. Talend - if familiar with eclipse and Java
2. Jitterbit - easy to use

Hope this helps